# string doesnt print out correctly using str replace

Tags: php, str-replace

So here is my code. I have to replace a space with an asterisk and if there are an occurence of two spaces in a row in the string replace it with one dash

```
<?php
$string = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$search = array(' ','  ');
$search2 = array('*','-');
echo str_replace($search, $search2, $string);
?>
```

when i run it it prints out

```
Keep*your****spacing***perfect!
```

which is suppose to be

```
Keep*your--spacing-*perfect!
```

so what is wrong with my code and how do i fix it? I did some research but could not come to a solution. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to swap your replaces. Because you replace single space **before** replacing double spaces.

```
$string = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$search = array('  ',' '); // swap !
$search2 = array('-','*'); // swap !
echo str_replace($search, $search2, $string);
```

Outputs:

```
Keep*your--spacing-*perfect!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$string1 = preg_replace("/\s\s/", "-", $string);
$string2 = preg_replace("/\s/", '*', $string1);
echo $string2;
?>
```

The output of this is the following:

```
Keep*your--spacing-*perfect!
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this line in the [PHP manual entry for `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If `search` or `replace` are arrays, their elements are processed first to last.

So just put the order of the array values in the opposite order:

```
<?php
$string = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$search = array('  ',' ');
$search2 = array('-','*');
echo str_replace($search, $search2, $string);
```